# How to make sure your cassandra client is only aware of the local data center nodes?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have multi data centers with many nodes and i need to let the client to connect to the local data center (nearest data center) first and if the local data center (nearest data center) is downed lets it connect to the remote data center.

I had added tow contact points from every data center.

How the client will recognize the nearest data center ?

I'm using java driver 3.0.0 in the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/load_balancing/#dc-aware-round-robin-policy) `DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy`:

This policy queries nodes of the local data-center in a round-robin fashion; optionally, it can also try a configurable number of hosts in remote data centers if all local hosts failed.

Call `withLocalDc` to specify the name of your local datacenter. You can also leave it out, and the driver will use the datacenter of the first contact point that was reached at initialization. However, remember that the driver shuffles the initial list of contact points, so this assumes that all contact points are in the local datacenter. In general, providing the datacenter name explicitly is a safer option.

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
       .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
       .withLoadBalancingPolicy(
               DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder()
                       .withLocalDc("myLocalDC")
                       .withUsedHostsPerRemoteDc(2)
                       .allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel()
                       .build()
       ).build();
```